# Prepend existing array of last names with first names from separate array of full names

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have a main data source which only contains last names in the order I need. I have scraped a target to obtain an unorganized list of full names in an array. Is it possible to prepend the last_names array with the matching first names of the full_names array based on correlating last names?

**Last Name Array Example Output (data I use in order I need)**

```
$last_name_array[0] = "Jones"
$last_name_array[1] = "Jang"
$last_name_array[2] = "Smith Jr"
$last_name_array[3] = "Johnson"
$last_name_array[4] = "Wall"
$last_name_array[5] = "Doe"
```

**Full Name Array Example Output (data I have to make names full)**

```
$full_name_array[0] = "John Smith Jr"
$full_name_array[1] = "R.A. Jones"
$full_name_array[2] = "Bob Johnson"
$full_name_array[3] = "Bing-Ho Jang"
$full_name_array[4] = "CA Doe"
$full_name_array[5] = "Eli Wall"
```

Comment: Need to show examples of input arrays and result.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, it is possible.**

Let's say this is your ordered list of last names:

```
$lastNames = [
    "Doggett",
    "Krycek",
    "Mulder",
    "Scully"
];
```

Let's further say this is your unordered list of full names:

```
$fullNames = [
    "Dana Scully",
    "Walter Skinner",
    "John Doggett",
    "Jeffrey Spender",
    "Fox Mulder",
    "Decoy Doe"
];
```

There are plenty of ways to solve this, some better than others.
I'm going to *outline* the most naive (and slow) solution, feel free to improve upon it.

1. Iterate over every `$name` in `$lastNames`
2. For each `$name`, check if it is contained in `$fullNames`
3. If so, replace the `$name` in `$lastNames` with the entry from `$fullNames`

In our case, this would yield:

```
$lastNames = [
    "John Doggett",
    "Krycek",
    "Fox Mulder",
    "Dana Scully"
];
```

**Note** that you need to be careful with step 2, as someone could have a first name that is similar to someone else's last name or vice versa. I would suggest you therefore only compare to the last *n* characters of the full names, where *n* is the length of the last name.